# Custom delivery UI extension generates "Invalid Class Name" error

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I've done nothing more than compile the [sample SSRS delivery extension](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!Printer%20Delivery%20Extension%20Sample) and deploy it to the server as per instructions. When I make a call to the *ReportService2010* `ListExtensions` web service method, the extension shows up in the list of results. However, when I go to create a subscription in the *Report Manager*, as soon as I choose the *Printer Delivery Sample* from the drop-down list of available delivery extensions, I get this error:

> Invalid Class Name

I'm running SSRS 2012 SP2 (11.0.5569.0) on Windows Server 2012 R2.

**EDIT: I found this in the logs:**

It turns out that the ReportManager (the ASP.NET UI) *does* log to the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSxx.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles` directory. I initially saw only subscription- (i.e. service-)related events in those files and assumed that if the ReportManager did log, those files must be elsewhere.

> extensionfactory!ReportManager_0-3!53c!06/02/2015-16:27:40:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating Printer Delivery Sample report server extension:
>
> **`System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`**
>
> ```
> at System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
> at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionClassFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9.<GetExtensionLocalizedName>b__6()
> at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Run>b__0(Object state)
> at System.Security.SecurityContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
> at System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(ContextBody callback)
> at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionClassFactory.GetExtensionLocalizedName(Extension extConfig, Boolean removeFailuresAndContinue)
> ```
>
> The action that failed was:
>
> `InheritanceDemand`
>
> The type of the first permission that failed was:
>
> `System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission`
>
> The first permission that failed was:
>
> ```
> <IPermission class="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Level="Minimal"/>
> ```
>
> The demand was for:
>
> ```
> <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1">
>   <IPermission class="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Level="Minimal"/>
> </PermissionSet>
> ```
>
> The granted set of the failing assembly was:
>
> ```
> <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1">
>   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="Execution"/>
>   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.StrongNameIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" PublicKeyBlob="00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001009D92F3DD932D20261ADD96F81554DD22E89D6C820CE81177D791891A9415FE8499B0A22270329D737DD29FCF15784BCE44B876E2099FA06B113712581C764E7B033E3F487EA8774CB78CB79FA5951A501F4FA61496F0E07AB2A48020A99435C0F2DE60282540E72CCCB63F05ECEFB90BD542E30EE34AA8005C51F2EC0BF606C0" Name="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.PrinterDeliverySample" AssemblyVersion="1.0.5627.17054"/>
>   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UrlIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Url="file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER/Reporting Services/ReportManager/bin/Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.PrinterDeliverySample.DLL"/>
>   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ZoneIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Zone="MyComputer"/>
> </PermissionSet>
> ```
>
> The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
>
> `Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.PrinterDeliverySample, Version=1.0.5627.17054, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0209f2bcebc8576`
>
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
>
> `MyComputer`
>
> The Url of the assembly that failed was:
>
> `file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER/Reporting Services/ReportManager/bin/Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.PrinterDeliverySample.DLL`

Yes, I feel a bit foolish. Okay - now what do I do with this information? Time to brush up on Code Access Security again...

Comment: Cross-posted as [an issue on CodePlex](https://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/workitem/21886).

Comment: I have not seen any relevant hints in the Windows Application event log. I'm not sure where else I could look for additional information - this doesn't seem like something that the Fusion log would pick up, would it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SSRS service?

Comment: Yes, I've even restarted the server.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. My log states however gives this `error: ERROR: Exception caught instantiating Roambi Business report server extension: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed`I dont know if you have something like that too? but it seems something with permissions

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the ReportManager component *does* log to the same log as the ReportServer. I'm getting that error as well.

Comment: Have you tried to update the ReportManager config file (`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<InstanceName>\Reporting Services\ReportManager\rsmgrpolicy.config`) and change the `PermissionSet` to `FullTrust` for the required `CodeGroups`? You can change all of them and see if it fixes the issue, then you could spot the right `CodeGroup` and apply the change only to it. Don't forget to backup your config file first.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2010/06/09/system-security-securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-web-aspnethostingpermission-failed.aspx

Try switching the Application Pool Identity to Network Service. Also, check your DLL to see if it needs to be unblocked, which is also mentioned in that article.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please confirm your failed assembly available/registered at C:\windows\assembly of reportserver machine. if its not registered then try to install that in GAC "Install an Assembly into the Global Assembly Cache"

[Global Assembly Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Naveen, installing my extension assembly in the GAC is not part of the recommended practice for installing SSRS extensions (which you can find by following the link in the question).